# Rails 4 Capistrano 3 deploy error public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am getting:

> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host
>   xxxxxx: cp exit status: 1 cp stdout: Nothing written cp stderr: cp:
>   cannot stat
>   ‘/home/app/releases/20141125030224/public/assets/manifest*’: No such
>   file or directory

Any work around. I deleted shared/public/assets on my server, still the same.

Comment: There is nos /user/ directory and /app/ directory in the path !
Is that normal ?

Comment: @user1883793 Might be you don't have releases folder with specific id

Comment: It work after I reboot the server : (, waste my time

Answer (score 1):

Create your manifest file first:

```
cap production deploy:compile_assets
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question, but I came across this problem today as well.  The bug in capistrano-rails is apparently fixed in the master branch on github, according to this issue:

https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/111

So, corrected the line in my gemfile to read:

```
gem 'capistrano-rails', github: 'capistrano/rails'
```

and the deploy works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After putting this on your gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano',  '~> 3.1'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
```

make sure you put the following on your capfile

```
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
```